# plugin architecture zoo example

Tags: c#

Trying to understand something that I don't know how to describe because I don't understand it :(

Let's say I'm making a zoo application and I would like to sell different animals for the zoo. I imagine having a IAnimal interface like the following:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
  string Talk { get; set; }
}
```

Now will I create a project for Cat and a project for Dog

```
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
...  
}
```

let's say i give away the zoo application and the user opens it, what's the code look like to check what animals this user has purchase?

Comment: You'll somehow need to identify which assemblies (projects) should be known by your Zoo application (whether that is scanning a directory or explicit configuration). Once you've done that you'll end up with a list of animal types found in the assemblies found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a prime case for [Dependency Injection](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/DependencyInjection.htm) using the [Inversion of Control](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InversionOfControl.htm) pattern.  [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html) is an open source project that allows you to inject dependencies into your application.  It allows you to say, "In this assembly, find all of the implementations of a particular interface and allow me to create an instance of any of those implementations".  This loose coupling makes for easier unit testing scenarios as well.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the amount of pluggability required it may be worth investigating [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx), the documentation includes a sample calculator app that should help.